# MudBlazor NavMenu - Is there a way to deselect (unhighlight) a MudNavLink by code?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor, .net-8.0

I have a MudNavMenu in Blazor, and when I click on one of the menu links, the previously clicked Menu link remains highlighted

For example, in the attached image, I click on Dashboard, the menu is selected in the off white colour correctly. When I then click on "People", the people menu is selected in the off white colour but the Dashboard menu remains selected in the off white. The page correctly navigates to the correct page, it is only that the Dashboard remains in the off white colour.

I think it may be because I am using the new Net 8 Blazor & Mudblazor has not been updated. I have all pages set to interactiveserver render mode, so all other Mudblazor buttons, tables etc are working.

I am wondering if there is anything I can reference in code to turn the selection off manually?

([image: picture attached]).

```
<MudNavMenu Bordered="true">
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Class="px-4 pt-2">My App</MudText>
    <br />
    <br />
    <MudNavLink Href="/" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Dashboard" IconColor="Color.Primary">Dashboard</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Href="/people" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.People" IconColor="Color.Secondary">People</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Href="/billing" Disabled="true" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Receipt">Billing</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavGroup Title="Settings" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Settings">
        <MudNavLink Href="/users" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.People" IconColor="Color.Success">Users</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/security" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Security" IconColor="Color.Info">Security</MudNavLink>
    </MudNavGroup>
</MudNavMenu>
```

Comment: so do you not want the active link to be highlighted at all?

Comment: Yes if possible I would like the active link to be highlighted, but have considered it might be easier to just disable the highlight altogether, however I am not sure how to do that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the highlight, you can set the Color property for `MudNavMenu` which sets the the color of the active NavLink, to `Color.Transparent`.

```html
<MudNavMenu Bordered="true" Color="Color.Transparent">
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Class="px-4 pt-2">My App</MudText>
    <br />
    <br />
    <MudNavLink Href="/" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Dashboard" IconColor="Color.Primary">Dashboard</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Href="/people" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.People" IconColor="Color.Secondary">People</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Href="/billing" Disabled="true" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Receipt">Billing</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavGroup Title="Settings" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Settings">
        <MudNavLink Href="/users" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.People" IconColor="Color.Success">Users</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/security" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Security" IconColor="Color.Info">Security</MudNavLink>
    </MudNavGroup>
</MudNavMenu>
```

Or you can override the CSS class that will be applied to the MudNavLink when
the link is active using the `MudNavLink.ActiveClass` property.

```html
<style>
    .my-custom-active{
     border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>

<MudNavMenu Bordered="true">
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Class="px-4 pt-2">My App</MudText>
    <br />
    <br />
    <MudNavLink ActiveClass="my-custom-active" Href="/" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Dashboard" IconColor="Color.Primary">Dashboard</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Href="/people" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.People" IconColor="Color.Secondary">People</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Href="/billing" Disabled="true" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Receipt">Billing</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavGroup Title="Settings" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Settings">
        <MudNavLink Href="/users" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.People" IconColor="Color.Success">Users</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/security" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Security" IconColor="Color.Info">Security</MudNavLink>
    </MudNavGroup>
</MudNavMenu>
```

Here's some demos [MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GYQnllmgIXSIFUIo)

Comment: Thank you very much! Both solutions helped and furthered my understanding.
I did some more testing with your above solutions and discovered that the highlighting only gets stuck on for the Href="/" link. I've removed this link and now the menu works perfectly. I don't think I would have figured it out without your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Match="NavLinkMatch.All" fixed the issue.

Comment: Exactly, there are two `NavLinkMatch` options that you can assign to the Match attribute of the `<NavLink>` element:
`NavLinkMatch.All`: The NavLink is active when it matches the entire current URL.
`NavLinkMatch.Prefix` (default): The `NavLink` is active when it matches any prefix of the current URL.